# How to set default value with Auto Value Gson 1.0.0

Tags: java, android, auto-value

Have had a very old version of [Auto Value Gson](https://github.com/rharter/auto-value-gson) (0.4.4alpha) from Ryan Harter. Now we want to migrate to something more current (1.0.0). However, something that is missing for me are the default values of the properties when deserializing - I used to be able to do something like

```
public static TypeAdapter<Highlighted> typeAdapter(Gson gson) {
      return new AutoValue_MyObjects.GsonTypeAdapter(gson)
                     .setDefaultOptions(new ArrayList<>());
}
```

And now the default methods do not seem to be supported any longer. Any ideas how I can achieve what I used to have in the newer version?

Comment: did you able to solve it? i am struggling with the same problem

Comment: It turned out this default thing was never part of the original library, it was patched and served in my company's artifactory. Not contributed back to the open source. I have always said this is stupid thing to do and now history teaches us once again never to do that. Now being forced to merge between two distinct branches I just gave up

Comment: i ended up writing my own type adapter that used the auto_value builder instead of the constructor, thus allowing to get the default values from the builder.